# Site width conflicting with device width

Tags: mobile, media-queries, css

I'm having a slight issue with my width=100%  css rule. On desktop browsers it's fine, however on mobile, it only uses 100% of the device width. So On a phone I'll end up have a div that spans 480px rather than across the entire horizontal screen.

Thanks for your help!

```
#intro {background-color: #1F1F1F; width: 100%; margin: auto; display:block;}
#intro-inner {height:450px; width:1105px; padding-top:50px;display:block;margin:0 auto;position:relative;}
```

On the HTML page, the intro inner div is inside the intro div. The background color is blue. On a desktop the site appears fine. However on a mobile after the devise width, ex. 480px, the  #intro div background and it's color ends.

Comment: width=100% on what? that looks like a attribute on a `table` ?

Comment: post your CSS here & accept answers for your questions.

Comment: Sure I'll post it in a second. And believe me I'd love to accept answers however thus far the issues I've had haven't been solved on here. So hopefully this will be a first!

Comment: width=100% on a div. I would like it to span across the entire site.